# refresh page in POST and keep all parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how can I refresh a page using javascript and keep all the parameters in the POST method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location.reload();
```

Will do that, but if the current page is the direct response to a POST request then the user will get a browser dialogue confirming the re-POST before the page reloads.

If that's no good you would have to create a new `<form>` element with `method="post"` and `action` pointing to the current URL. You would have to do this from the server-side to duplicate all the POSTed parameters as `<input type="hidden">` (and file uploads can't be replicated).

Depending on what you are doing, you may be able to use the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) model to stop most pages being POST responses, allowing you to refresh without prompting.

Comment: Will location.reload() repeat the POST as well?